# How to get the offset of an automatic (local) variable relative to the stack frame ( __builtin_frame_address )

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Using gcc, I need to track the existence of some special kind of variables allocated in various routines as local variables.
In order to do that I have thought to signal their existence at compile time.
So I need at compile time a method to get the offset of an automatic variable (variable with local scope) relative to the stack frame (relative to rbp register in x86 architectures).

I am already able to get it as follows:

```
(char*)&a - (char*)__builtin_frame_address(0)
```

the problem is that gcc isn't smart enough and generates a lot of instructions for what should just be the loading of a constant.
So I am wondering if by chance there is any hidden macro or builtin that gives it to me directly as that is too the simpler solution.

Comment: What about good old trick - having dummy var first and taking difference in addresses between dummy and your variable

Comment: What you suggest is similar to the code I included. The fact is that in order to do it, it takes the frame pointer adds to it the known fixed offset of the variable (in order to get it's address) and afterwards subtracts the frame pointer in order to find the already known fixed offset. I think there should be a better way.

Comment: This is a very dangerous function, it is quite incompatible with the optimizer.  It *really* needs an MCVE, but the long view is that you either get a lot of code because you correctly disabled the optimizer or it needs a lot of code because the optimizer eliminated the frame pointer.  Be sure to compile with -Wframe-address in effect.

Comment: I compiled with options -O;-Wall;-std=c++1z;-enable-frame-pointer; the code produced is: lea    -0x38(%rbp),%rax    mov    %rbp,%rcx
sub    %rax,%rcx mov    %rcx,(%rbx)

Comment: gcc is smart enough to not apply optimizations to problems that never happen. You're probably the first person ever to conceive this convoluted solution to whatever your actual problem is. The code gcc generated gives you the exact result you need. Could there be a peephole optimization that realizes that `lea X(%r1),%r2 sub %r1, %r2` is equivalent to `mov X, %r2`? Sure. But this situation probably never happens except in contrived situations like this. No point in wasting everyone elses compilation time on it. I'd say that gcc is being very smart here.

Answer (score 5):

> Using gcc, I need to track the existence of some special kind of variables allocated in various routines as local variables

Just because a variable has automatic storage doesn't mean it will exist on the stack. The compiler may just stick it in a register depending on how it's being used.

> So I need at compile time a method to get the offset of an automatic variable (variable with local scope) relative to the stack frame (relative to rbp register in x86 architectures).

This doesn't make any sense. The stack frame doesn't exist at compile-time. What happens if the compiler decides to inline your function? Where is the compile-time stack frame?

> I am already able to get it as follows:

```
(char*)&a - (char*)__builtin_frame_address(0)
```

That's one way to do it, and it handles the cases where the compiler shuffles around your stack frame.

> the problem is that gcc isn't smart enough and generates a lot of instructions for what should just be the loading of a constant.

That's because it's *not* a constant. A stack frame is the *not* the BSS. The addresses may not be calculable at link time. Again, the inliner completely breaks your preconceptions of what the stack frame is. You may want to read [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) on `__builtin_return_address`.

---

The simplest solution is the one that Severin Pappadeux suggested:

```
void foo() {
    int base = 0;
    // do stuff
    float my_special_var = 42.0f;
    std::ptrdiff_t special_var_offset = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&base) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&my_special_var);
    std::cout << special_var_offset << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: a) When I get the address of a variable (as in the case of the code shown) the compiler is obliged to store it in an address reachable location - or at least behave as if. b) Regarding inlining, indeed the compiler may choose to inline. I have managed it using __attribute__((noinline)) .

Comment: Any way also when it is inlined I have seen that these variables are put on the parent stack frame as if defined directly there. It doesn't changes my problem as I just want to know the location of the variable relative to the current stack frame independently from which it is. The solution of Severin is no different than the one indicated by me initially and the code I suppose will be bloated in the same manner.

Comment: Regarding your phrase "A stack frame is the not the BSS. The addresses may not be calculable at link time." I think it isn't true because if the address of a variable isn't calculable at compile time why the compiler is able to compile the correct instructions referring to the variables as locations with a fixed offset from the base pointer ? ( or at least as moving offsets from the SP if the Base pointer isn't used ).

Comment: By the way besides having all those objections on your comments, the pragmatic fact is that gcc correctly individuates in that case that the result resolves in a fixed offset and compiles accordingly                movq   $0xfffffffffffffffc,0x8(%rbx)
movq   $0xfffffffffffffff8,0x10(%rbx)
movq   $0xfffffffffffffff4,0x18(%rbx) so the answer of Severin seems at least to give the desirable result but still it isn't the desired way of doing it. In case that it doesn't follows in the next 2 days an answer related to some builtin into the compiler I will accept it as the correct one.